# Pass data from an Angular modal's controller back to the main controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, controller, modal-dialog

Here is the thing. I am not able to pass data from angular modal back to the controller where i need it. the codes given below.

Controller side

```
'use strict'
var DataMod = angular.module('Data', ["angularGrid", 'ui.bootstrap.contextMenu', 'ui.bootstrap']);
DataMod.controller('DataController', ['$scope', '$compile', '$uibModal', '$log','$rootScope', '$http', function ($scope, $compile, $uibModal,$log, $rootScope, $http, ngUtilityService) {



//user first clicks on Add button. A modal opens up. ModalInstanceCtrl is the controller used.
$scope.adduser = function () {
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
});
 //response data should be available here.  
};


var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
//ajax call is made is inside this controller and i get a response. 
//this response is an object. i need to pass this object back to the adduser function. mentioned it above. 
};


}
]);
```

As you can see above, there is the main controller. I have used a modal inside there which has its own controller. I make ajax call inside that modals controller and get a response back.

I want that response as a result to be available back at the adduser function so that i can work with that data. However, it seems that once the adduser function starts, it goes to the ModalInstanceCtrl and ends its execution there. It doesnt come back to the adduser function at all. I need a way to get back to the adduser function.

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this. Also how to pass the object response from ModalInstanceCtrl to the main controller inside adduser function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Angular Bootstrap Modal, yes? First, I would set it up so that the modal controller is separated out from the main controller. Second, you are missing the promise needed to pass the response from the modal to the main controller. You can read about the return modal instance in the docs here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

This is the example code from the Angular Bootstrap plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/nGjBtMp33pFDAQ6r7Tew?p=info

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
};
  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Comment: Updated answer with new link

Comment: thanks. does it mean that modalInstance.result.then is the place where the modals data will return and i can use this data to perform further operations :?

Comment: Yep, thats right. In the example that is where selectedItem is being assigned to the select property of the main controller scope and it can now be manipulated in main controller. $scope.selected = selectedItem;