# Modal popup in a modal popup using angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I'm trying to open modal popup in another modal popup. I'm getting the following error

> angular.min-1.2.29.js:93 Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.29/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalInstanceNewProvider%20%3C-%20%24modalInstanceNew
>       at Error (native)

Below is my code

## Outer Modal code

```
var OuterController = function($scope, $modalInstance, $timeout, $http, $window, $rootScope, mydetails,$modal) {

    $scope.openInnerModal = function(){

        var modalInstanceNew = $modal.open({

              templateUrl: '../../TEST-ANOTHER.html',
              controller: InnerController,
              resolve: {
                  lDetails: function(){
                      return mydetails;
                  }
              }
           });
    }
    $scope.cancel = function () {       
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');       
    }
}
```

## Inner Modal Code

```
 var InnerController = function($scope, $modalInstanceNew,$timeout, $http, $window, $rootScope,lDetails,$modal) {   
        alert(lDetails);
        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstanceNew.dismiss('cancel');
        }   
    }
```

Comment: `$modalInstanceNew` is not an angular injector. only `$modalInstance` is

Comment: I have created the modalInstance in the same way as modalInstanceNew

Comment: "I have created the modalInstance in the same way" - What do you want to tell us?

Comment: var modalInstance = $modal.open({

              templateUrl: '../../TEST-OUTER.html',
              controller: OuterController,
              resolve: {
                  lDetails: function(){
                      return mydetails;
                  }
              }
           });
    }

Like this

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying `$modalInstanceNew` is not a known provider. Which is exactly true. It should be `$modalInstance` instead.

Try the inner modal code like this:

```
var InnerController = function($scope, $modalInstance,$timeout, $http, $window, $rootScope,lDetails,$modal) {   
        alert(lDetails);
        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }   
    }
```

Comment: yeah this works,can we share the  modalInstance with two different controllers ?

Comment: @Ashok why not? because both are in different scopes.

Comment: Can we pass the data from inner controller to outer controller by this way ?

Comment: @Ashok see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945236/pass-data-from-an-angular-modals-controller-back-to-the-main-controller for passing data to the parent controller.